# Change HTTP status code in Jekyll

Tags: http-status-code-404, jekyll

I'm using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) to generate my website. When you add a file called 404.html to your web root and a page isn't found in a Jekyll website, then Jekyll will automatically display the contents of the 404.html file to the user. However, it does so with an unchanged URL (but, with a correct HTTP status return code of 404).

In order to be able to log errors in Google Analytics (and set a Custom Alert to alert me of any 404's), I want to forward the error page to /404/?broken=url-goes-here. This page unfortunately, returns a HTTP status code of 200. This leads to the main question:

How do I get a page to return a different status code than 200 in Jekyll? The original page that is fetched upon an error correctly returns 404, but my /404/ page returns 200, and I want it to return 404 (preferably without using any Jekyll Plugins, AJAX or Javascript).

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

In Github pages, you can set a [custom 404.html page](https://help.github.com/articles/custom-404-pages/).
The name must be `404.html`.

The http returned code is 404.

You can then catch this in analytics.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! I'm using a custom hosted version of Jekyll, so any Github pages features unfortunately aren't available to me. Do you know of any way to do this without using GH pages?

Comment: What do you mean by 'custom hosted' ? If you have access to server configuration you can declare an error page and then have correct http code returned.